# Magento 2.3.2 checkout success page Create an Account Button Not Display

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.3.2, order-success-page

I am working on a Magento 2.3.2. In checkout success page, The **Create an Account** button is not display.

I have checked all files but it is not disabled in any files.

How to solve this one. Please tell me.

I have checked into the whole project but no any **'checkout.registration'** field is removed into the file. Please check below screenshot:
[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The functionality should be in the OSC extension configuration.

Comment: Is there any console errors in checkout page?

Comment: @Sumit Please tell me in brief

Comment: @jafarpinjar there is no any console errors

Comment: I'm using OneStepCheckout extension for a website and it is providing the feature to enable/disable the Create an Account button on the order success page.

Comment: @HardikMakwana, Is any customization done related to checkout? if yes, pls check the layout file if the checkout.registration is set to remove..

Comment: Hello @jafarpinjar, I have checked into the whole project but no checkout.registration remove into the layout file. Please see screenshot into the updated question.I have used the MGS_Clause Theme.

Comment: after enabling from admin, please flush cache and redeploy static content and try again.

Comment: then some modification is done in that theme, need to check it, pls try once disabling that theme to confirm whether its working in luma theme or not?